# Checkmark on cell of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my UITableView called _selectAttributes I want to put and remove a checkmark when I tap on each cell.
This is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell * cell = [_selectAttributes cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType != UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work well, but when I scroll up and down the table, checkmarks appear on other cells and disappear on the previous ones.

How can I solve?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCellAccessory Disappears When Scrolled Off Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827034/uitableviewcellaccessory-disappears-when-scrolled-off-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an `NSIndexPath` property named `selectedIndexPath`.

Then have your delegate methods `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedIndexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:
I wasn't paying attention that you want solution for multiple cell selection. My answer obviously solves problem only for single cell selection, but I believe its a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an NSArray of selected index paths. On `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, add the index path to that array and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check whether the index path is in the array and set the UITableViewCell's accessory type accordingly.

Comment: By the way, the behavior you are seeing is a result of how UITableView reuses cells. The table view does this for performance reasons but it can create headaches in a number of ways. I would recommend getting familiar with cell reuse as a concept if you are not already.